# How to upload files using java?

Tags: java, struts2

the scenario is as follows,

user clicks on upload images, then a three upload file fields will be shown to upload three images, there is also a button to add more images, user can upload unlimited number of images but clicking on that button to show more upload file fields, I am not sure how to implement this. There are many examples but none of them do upload more images feature.

I have the following code but not sure how to implement the button to upload more images

```
<s:form action="uploadImages" method="POST" encytype="multipart/form-data">
        <s:file label="File 1" name="fileUpload"/>
        <s:file label="File 2" name="fileUpload"/>
        <s:file label="File 3" name="fileUpload"/>
        <s:submit value="submit" name="Upload"/>
    </s:form>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is not difficult.

Inside your javascript, keep track of a counter value starting from counter = 0

Create your first upload field as:

`<input type="file" name="file[0]">`

Whenever a user clicks 'Upload more images...', use JavaScript to increment the counter, then append a new file input field:

`<input type="file" name="file[1]">`

And so on...

```
<input type="file" name="file[2]">
<input type="file" name="file[3]">
<input type="file" name="file[4]">
<input type="file" name="file[5]">
```

When you submit the form, all the images will be submitted to the server, and you can use a loop to process each uploaded image one by one.

To add a new file input field quickly, I recommend using jQuery.
First, set an id on your form as seen below:

```
<s:form id="myForm" action="uploadImages" method="POST" encytype="multipart/form-data">
    <s:file label="File 1" name="file[0]"/>
    <s:file label="File 2" name="file[1]"/>
    <s:file label="File 3" name="file[2]"/>
    <s:submit value="submit" name="Upload"/>
</s:form>
```

Then, add a new input field like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var counter = 3;

    function onAddMoreButtonClicked() {
        for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            $("#myForm").append($("<input>").attr({"type" : "file", "name" : "file["+counter + "]"}));
            counter = counter + 1;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: thanks for your swift response, but how to add a new input field ? do you know of any sample code?

Comment: thanks Where should I put the button to be clicked for more input fileds?

Answer (score 0):

comming from form multypart
in a post method try

make @Autowired ServletContext c; 
or take object from it in servlets

```
        byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();

         String UPLOAD_FOLDEdR=c.getRealPath("/images");     
        Path path = Paths.get(UPLOAD_FOLDEdR +"/"+ file.getOriginalFilename());
        Files.write(path, bytes);
```